# Excel VBA - How to select Range down to first blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to write the code for a Macro on Excel. Any help greatly appreciated :)

Currently my code selects the range C6:C10 in 'Leaves Records' and inserts at B2 in 'Old Records', shifting all cells down. I want to do exactly the same thing but instead of copying C6:C10, I want to copy ALL cells in 'Leaves Records' from B2 down to the first blank cell in Column B.

This is the code I have (which copies C6:C10):

```
Sub CopyToFirstBlankCell()
Dim bookingWS As Worksheet, mainWS As Worksheet
Dim copyRng As Range

Set bookingWS = Sheets("Leaves Records")
Set mainWS = Sheets("Old Records")
Set copyRng = bookingWS.Range("C6:C10")

mainWS.Range("B2:B" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
copyRng.Copy mainWS.Range("B2")
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have information in other cells in `Leave Records`?

Comment: Yeah, I need it to select and copy ONLY column B, from B2 down to the first blank cell (not including the blank cell). @paulinhax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you can try something like this:

```
Sub CopyToFirstBlankCell()
Dim bookingWS As Worksheet, mainWS As Worksheet
Dim copyRng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

Set bookingWS = Sheets("Leaves Records")
Set mainWS = Sheets("Old Records")

lastrow = bookingWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set copyRng = bookingWS.Range("B2:B" & lastrow)

mainWS.Range("B2:B" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
copyRng.Copy mainWS.Range("B2")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple code that copies cells until it comes upon empty one :)

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Leaves Records").Cells(i, 2)) 'it'll iterate through B column
    Sheets("Old Records").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Leaves Records").Cells(i, 2).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop
```